# Sorted output of free space of partition

Tags: linux, bash

Sorted output of free space for each partition.
In other words, a table with at least two columns: partition name and free or unsupported storage space sorted according to free or unused storage space.
Motivation: I want to back up files and use a hard drive that still has as much space as possible.

what i tried:

`df -h | sort -h -r`

if found that's sound great

`diskutil info disk1s4 | awk '/Free Space:.* GB/ {print $3,$4}'`

but not working at my Manjaro-Linux. Command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I guess you meant "use partition" instead of hard drive.

```
df -l --output=source,avail|sed '/\/dev\//!d'|sort -nr -k2
```

Notes:

- `-l` only local devices, that is, network shares are not listed
- the `sed` part removes the title and filesystems not under `/dev/` adjust this if you want something else.
- `sort` does sort.
- the mountpoints are not listed, if they are required, add `target` in the `--output` list.

Comment: Yes, I added the mountpoints and size and changed the order slightly: `df -l --output=avail,size,source,target|sed '/\/dev\//!d'|sort -nr -k2`

Comment: i adet -h for make make df command display the output in human-readable format. `df -h -l --output=avail,size,source,target|sed '/\/dev\//!d'|sort -nr -k2`